# Express, Multer, and Cloudinary not returning full cloudinary response

Tags: node.js, express, multer, cloudinary

I'm using Multer/multer-storage-cloudinary to upload images directly to Cloudinary rather first uploading it to a local temp directory, then sending it to Cloudinary:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router({mergeParams:true});
if (app.get('env') == 'development'){ require('dotenv').config(); }
const crypto = require('crypto');
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;
const { CloudinaryStorage } = require('multer-storage-cloudinary');
const multer = require('multer');
const { storage } = require('../cloudinary');
const upload = multer({storage});

//configure cloudinary upload settings
cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name:process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET
});

const storage = new CloudinaryStorage({
    cloudinary: cloudinary,
    folder: ('book_tracker/'+process.env.CLOUDINARY_FOLDER+'posts'),
    allowedFormats: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'],
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        let buf = crypto.randomBytes(16);
        buf = buf.toString('hex');
        let uniqFileName = file.originalname.replace(/\.jpeg|\.jpg|\.png/ig, '');
        uniqFileName += buf;
        
        console.log(req.body);
      cb(undefined, uniqFileName );
    }
  });

const middleware = {
    function asyncErrorHandler: (fn) =>
        (req, res, next) => {
            Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next))
                         .catch(next);
        }
}


/* POST create user page  */
router.post('/register', upload.single('image'), asyncErrorHandler(postRegister));
```

What I'm running into is that the response I'm getting in `req.file` is not the full Cloudinary response which includes public_id, etc. Instead it's like this:

```js
{
  fieldname: 'image',
  originalname: 'My Headshot.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  path: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/<cloudinary_name>/image/upload/v1611267647/<public_id>.jpg',
  size: 379632,
  filename: '<public_id>'
}
```

It's been a while since I worked with multer-storage-cloudinary, though that `storage` was taken directly from an old project that would return the correct information. Is there something in multer, or multer-storage-cloudinary, that I need to set in order to put the full cloudinary response into req.file?

Comment: I know nothing about cloudinary, but is it possible it's a streaming response that asyncErrorHandler isn't accounting for?

Comment: @Chris I'd almost agree with you, except this isn't a truncated version of the cloudinary response, it's taking the response and assigning that handful of values to new keys. See "Sample Response" here: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference
`path` here is `secure_url` in the cloudinary response, the same with `filename` is `public_id` from cloudinary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `multer-storage-cloudinary` package is a third party package that integrates multer and Cloudinary in a streamlined way, but it doesn't expose all possible options or responses from the Cloudinary SDK or API

In your example, it's not returning the full API response from Cloudinary, but a subset of the fields, because the `file` object's `filename`, `path`, and `size` properties are taken from the Cloudinary API response (from the `public_id`, `secure_url`, and `bytes` properties of the API response respectively), but the other fields aren't mapped: https://github.com/affanshahid/multer-storage-cloudinary#file-properties

If you need the full set of response values (or some specific values not mapped already) you can:

- Ask the package maintainer to add support for other fields
- Fork the package and map additional fields yourself; the fields are mapped here though I'm not sure what else may need to be changed: https://github.com/affanshahid/multer-storage-cloudinary/blob/1eb903d44ac6dd42eb1ab655b1e108acd97ed4ca/src/index.ts#L83-L86
- Switch from using that package for wrapping the Cloudinary SDK to use the Cloudinary SDK directly in your own code, so you can handle the response directly.
- Leave it as it is now and make a separate call to the Cloudinary Admin API to fetch the other details of the image(s): https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#get_resources
- Leave it as-is, but add a notification_url so that as well as the API call response, the details of the new upload will be sent in an HTTP POST request to a URL of your choice: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/notifications

  - The notification_url can be specified in the Upload API call, Upload Preset, or at the account-level in the Cloudinary account settings.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll go with that third option.